# $yy''=y^2y'+(y')^2$ method of reduction (differential equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about using reduction to solve

$$yy''=y^2y'+(y')^2$$

This is how I have been thinking:

put $y'=p$ and $p''=(dp)/(dy)*p$

$yp*dp/dy-y^2p-p^2=0$

...

$dp/dy-y=p/y$

but now I don't know how I can solve it? perhaps with integrating factor?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$p'-\frac{p}{y}=y \stackrel{\cdot e^{\int -\frac{1}{y} \mathrm{d}y}=\frac{1}{y}}{\iff} \frac{p'}{y}-\frac{p}{y^2}=1 \iff \frac{p'}{y} \left (\frac{1}{y}\right )_y p=1 \iff \left (\frac{p}{y}\right )_y=1 \iff p=cy+y^2$$

Notation; $$(X)_y=\frac {\mathrm{d}X}{\mathrm{d}y}$$

Comment: Thank so much, I got also this.

Comment: If you're confident that I helped you, you can accept the answer and upvote(if you have the privilege that is).